# How do I/can I recursively indent div's with a class?

Tags: css, html

I'm looking at a page of html code that follows this pattern:

```
<div id='1' class='someclass'>
  contents
  <div id='2' class='someclass'>
    other contents
    <div id='3' class='someclass'>
      yet even more contents
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm looking to indent the contents of the inner divs, without changing their class, such that the page will be displayed so:

```
contents
  other contents
    yet even more contents
```

Is this feasible through manipulation of 'someclass'? If so, how?

Note that the divs may contain some other, fairly simple html - such as headings, lists, etc...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think your looking for the following css rule

```
.someclass { margin-left: 10px; }
```

For no indent on the first item

```
.someclass .someclass { margin-left: 10px; }
```

Comment: There's a helpful discussion of this, with examples _(not text-based, but the same concepts apply)_, in this [2010 post](https://depage.net/en/blog/2010/11/rekursives-css.html) on Frank Hellenkamp's depage.net blog. _(Here's a [Wayback Machine archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20230809192735/https://depage.net/en/blog/2010/11/rekursives-css.html), just in case.)_ 

 Apparently a class is only required on one element _(if even that)_, not on every level; as a bonus, this keeps the markup cleaner. It really can 'cascade'!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure if this is what you're after, but you can do the following:

(sidenote: you should avoid starting a id or class with a number for crossbrowser compatibility)

```
div#div1 div {
  margin-left:20px;
}
```

This will display and indent of 20px on all the div's inside the parent div with id `div1`.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FCt5N/1/).

Answer (score -1):

You can do this, but it need create a container to cover it and give it a special ID like this :

```
#yourContainer div {
  padding-left:0px; 
}

#yourContainer div > div {
   padding-left:5px; 
}

#yourContainer div > div > div {
    padding-left:10px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="yourContainer">
    <div id="1" class='someclass'>
      contents
      <div id="2" class='someclass'>
        other contents
        <div id="3" class='someclass'>
          yet even more contents
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

if u want absolutly with class, try this

```
#yourContainer .someclass {
  padding-left:0px; 
}

#yourContainer .someclass > .someclass {
   padding-left:5px; 
}

#yourContainer .someclass > .someclass > .someclass {
    padding-left:10px;
}
```

U can so, replace "padding-left" by "margin-left", it's u the boss ;-)

Comment: Hi Gilbert! Your solution doesn't work for my purposes - what if i'm nesting 15 divs for example?

Comment: Sorry, but it was not precised in your question !

Comment: That's what the word "recursively" means ;)